# Python find most recent created file

Tags: python, file, directory

I'm trying to find the name of the most recently created file in a directory:

```
    try:
        #print "creating path"
        os.makedirs(self.path)
        self.dictName = "0"
    except OSError as exception:
        if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise
        listOfFiles = os.listdir(self.path)
        listOfFiles = filter(lambda x: not os.path.isdir(x), listOfFiles)
        print "creating newestDict"
        newestDict = max(listOfFiles, key=lambda x: os.stat(x).st_mtime) ------<
        print "setting self.name"
```

The arrow points where the code is causing the program to crash. Printing listOfFiles returns a non-empty list. This is using a third-party python program that has its own interpreter. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can clarify the process of listing files by using the `os.path.isfile()` function and a comprehension list, but that is up to you. If you look into the related link in the comments, you'll see the `os.path.getctime()`[function](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-os.path.html#l2h-2178), which allows you to get the creation time of a file in windows systems and the time of the last modification in Unix-like systems (like the `stat()`system call `st_mtime` attribute):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, getctime

listOfFiles = [f for f in listdir(self.path) if isfile(join(self.path,f))]
newestDict = max(listOfFiles, key=lambda x: getctime(x))
```

But so far, your code looks correct. Maybe we could be more helpful if you provide the error the interpreter is throwing or the full piece of code.